# Finder keeps presenting blank window

Tags: macos, finder

About the 3rd or 5th time after I relaunch finder or reboot and choose a new folder, the finder windows presents this image

[image]

Once this happens I can no longer interact with the window besides dragging it.I recently repaired disk permissions, and it is still happening. I am using the latest version of OSX Mavericks. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: what are the 3d party icons

Comment: Those are just apps and an automator script to clear out svn internals that i've pinned to the toolbar. its a standard feature of Finder. I've had those there for years with no problems.  http://www.wired.com/2013/10/finder-toolbar-app-shortcut/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem.  I created a new blank user and logged in there and it didn't happen, so I figured the problem had to be software related.  Turns out it was an application that recently updated called "display maid" which was causing the problem.  After i disabled that app, everything was fine.

Comment: so it was a 3d party after all :)